# Access variable attributes inside dplyr user defined function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, attr

I'm trying to create a function to compute weighted averages from survey data, where the variable name is taken from a variable attribute.
I have imported a dataset where each variable already has a label 
Here's a reproducible example:

```
random_df<- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
attr(random_df$X1, 'label') <-"Age"
attr(random_df$X2, 'label') <-"Gender"
attr(random_df$X3, 'label') <-"Occupation"
attr(random_df$X4, 'label') <-"Nationality"
attr(random_df$X5, 'label') <-"Education"
```

I would like to create a function that computes weighted averages and names the variables from the label. I tried the following

```
my_function<- function(var, ...){
  var<-enquo(var)
  group_var <- enquos(...)
  df <-random_df

label<-attr(df$!!var,'label')

  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!var))%>%
    group_by(!!!group_var) %>%
    count(!!var) %>%
    mutate(freq=n/sum(n)) %>%
    mutate(!!label:=percent(freq)) 

}
```

This however gives me an error `Error: unexpected '!' in:" label<-attr(df$!"`. Would anyone know how to fix the code?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
my_function<- function(var, ...){
  var <- enexpr(var) # use expression, not quosure
  group_var <- enquos(...)
  df <-random_df

  label<-attr(df[[as.character(var)]],'label') # use as.character, not unquoting

  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!var))%>%
    group_by(!!!group_var) %>%
    count(!!var) %>%
    mutate(freq=n/sum(n)) %>%
    mutate(!!label:=percent(freq)) 
}
```

We use `df[[as.character(var)]]` instead of `df$!!var` because unquoting with `!!` fails in [this case](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting-in-special-forms). Also note that you probably want expressions, not quosures here. For `as.character` we specifically need an expression.

(Thanks for updating with the reproducible example!)

Comment: Thanks Nick, that does the job!